# Unable to delete Google Cloud Storage object change notification webhook

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I created a webhook to monitor changes on a bucket in 2015 using the command `gsutil notification watchbucket https://my-project.appspot.com/myWebHook gs://my-bucket/`

Today I would like to delete it but I'm unable to do it.

`gsutil notification list -o gs://my-bucket/`  is showing me the current webhooks

It is returning something like that:

```
Notification channel 1:
        Channel identifier: someid-905e-905e-905e-1fdca170d689
        Resource identifier: myIdentifierXXXfncnI0SuU-U
        Application URL: url=https://my-project.appspot.com/myWebHook&appEngine=true
        Created by:
        Creation time: 2015-09-08 11:44:26.775000
```

when I try to delete it with the command `gsutil notification stopchannel someid-905e-905e-905e-1fdca170d689 myIdentifierXXXfncnI0SuU-U`

I get this:
`NotFoundException: 404 Channel 'someid-905e-905e-905e-1fdca170d689' not found for project '32555940559`'

All this is done with my account which is the owner of the project. By the way, the id of the project in the error message is not the one of my project

If I switch to a service account, I get a different error: `AccessDeniedException: 403 Caller not owner of subscription`

Do you have any idea how I could solve this?

Comment: the project 32555940559 seems to be owned by Google (google.com:cloudsdktool)

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation [Object change notification](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Authorization):

> There are three steps to configuring authorization in an object change
>   notification scenario:
>
> 1.Creating a Service Account
>
> 2.Configuring gsutil to Use the Service Account
>
> 3.Identifying a Domain to Receive Notifications

To be able to remove the notification channel you have to identify the service account used for creating the channel (owner service account of this channel). Then, you have to configure `gsutil` to use that specific service account and remove the notification channel. Therefore, trying to perform this action by authorizing `gsutil` using your personal account will not work.

Comment: In 2015, when I created my webhook, I think a service account was not required. So now I'm not sure I'll be able to delete it :/

Comment: I will suggest you to contact GCP Support [Cloud Support Procedures](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/procedures)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same problem and solved it by authenticating `gcloud` with my main default service account (this may have been the account used when creating the watcher):

```
 gcloud auth activate-service-account  my-project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com --key-file ~/Downloads/my-project-1234abcdef.json
```

I could then list all my watchers to get the Channel ID and Resource ID with

```
gsutil notification list -o gs://my-project.appspot.com/
```

Note that in this next command, I couldn't use the bucket path like `gs://my-project.appspot.com/` but rather had to use the goofy "Resource identifier" value from the `list` response above which looks like

```
Bucket my-project.appspot.com has the following active Object Change Notifications:
        Notification channel 1:
                Channel identifier: prod
                Resource identifier: asdf1234
                Application URL: url=https://my-project.appspot.com/api/gcs&appEngine=true
                Created by: 
                Creation time: 2019-02-11 16:16:07.955000
        Notification channel 2:
                Channel identifier: dev
                Resource identifier: 1234asdf
                Application URL: url=https://my-project.appspot.com/api/gcs&appEngine=true
                Created by: 
                Creation time: 2019-02-11 16:21:40.864000
```

This command then removed the prod channel:

```
gsutil notification stopchannel prod asdf1234
Removing channel prod with resource identifier asdf1234 ...
Succesfully removed channel.
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, unfortunately in my case when I use the default service account, I get that error: `AccessDeniedException: 403 Caller not owner of subscription`